# What is the difference between an adjective and a noun modifier?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, modifiers, participles

"My tire was **damaged**. I took the **damaged** tire to the garage."

In the above example, the book (summit) refers to the past participles of the transitive verbs as "noun modifiers" and not "adjectives". What is the difference between them, if any? How would you simply explain it to your students if you were an English teacher?
Would it be wrong to say that the participle "damaged" is an adjective in those sentences?

Thanks

Comment: The first statement is ambiguous.  It could mean "*My tire was damaged (but it no longer is).*" or it could mean "*My tire was damaged (in an accident).*".  In the first one, "damaged" is an adjective, while in the second one "damaged" is a past participle.  This might explain some of the confusion in the comments on some of the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grammatical terms are not always used consistently in different sources.  In general, the term [*noun modifier*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_modifier) is usually a broad term, often encompassing adjectives, nouns used to modify other nouns, verbs used as modifiers (usually past or present participles), and even phrases and clauses that modify a noun.

Some examples:

- Adjective: I took the *big* tire to the garage.
- Noun: I took the *truck* tire to the garage.
- Verb: I took the *damaged* tire to the garage.
- Verb: I took the *spinning* tire to the garage.
- Prepositional phrase: I took the tire *under my car* to the garage.
- Phrase with participle: I took the tire *damaged by the nail* to the garage.
- Clause: I took the tire, *which had been given to me by Uncle Joe after the war in exchange for two bottles of sarsaparilla and my solemn promise not to tell my parents about it,* to the garage.

Depending on the grammatical guide you're using, any or all of these things could be called "noun modifiers."

In contrast, an *adjective* is a specific part of speech.  Some grammar guides would allow the use of "adjective" to refer to things like your example of *damaged tire*, but others might limit the term to words that are not derived from other parts of speech, like *big*, *small*, *happy*, *funny*, etc., while referring to other words *functioning* as adjectives to be "participial adjectives" or within the broader category of "noun modifiers."  There's no question that in the second sentence the word is *functioning* as an adjective, whether one calls it that or not.

The problem with limiting the group of "adjectives" too much is that some adjectival forms created from verbs (and occasionally other parts of speech) acquire specific meanings and associations in their adjectival form.  For example, in the phrases *fallen angel* or *fallen woman*, the word *fallen* is not merely a past participle of *to fall*, but has acquired specific connotations.  Other verbal adjectives are based on archaic root words that are rarely or never used in their original form. For example, *dilapidated* is a common adjective, but the verb *dilapidate* has fallen out of a use for the most part, so has *dilapidated* become the primary word as an adjective now?  Dictionaries often differ in their choices about when to list a derived word as a separate adjective.

All of these cases make it rather difficult to draw a firm line between *adjective* versus other types of modifiers.  Nevertheless, if I were required to use a book that created such a distinction, and I had to explain the concept to a class of students, I'd start with the idea of adjectives as words not derived from forms of other parts of speech, as in my list above including *big* and so forth.

It's not a perfect explanation, but few grammatical terms are ever perfectly precise.

---

As a side note, there's a bit of a question about whether the word *damaged* in the first sentence, "My tire was damaged," is necessarily a noun modifier.  Depending on the broader grammatical context, it could also be the verb in a past continuous tense.  In the context "my tire was damaged yesterday by a nail," *damaged* is part of the verb.  Compare that with the context: "I ran over a nail last month.  Yesterday my tire was damaged; today it is repaired."  In that case, *damaged* is likely a noun modifier.  With the limited context given in your two sentences, it isn't even clear that *damaged* in the first sentence is even used in an adjective-like sense.

Comment: Nice answer. Do you have any authoritative type sources where we can find the "adjectives don't include words derived from past participles" type thinking you describe?

Comment: @Araucaria - no, I assumed OP had one, as that was what was stated in the question. I have never elsewhere heard this view expressed from an authoritative source, so I was giving OP the benefit of the doubt. It is, however, a common answer in internet questions about "Is this a participle or an adjective?" In my answer, I was trying to distinguish between what I'd call a *participial adjective* vs. a ("pure"?) *adjective* that would be listed under a separate headword in a dictionary as such. I assumed OP's book was trying to get at a similar distinction.

Comment: @Araucaria - I have edited my answer to try to clarify what I meant to say, which is slightly different from your interpretation of my original answer.

Answer (score 3):

An adjective is a lexical class of words.  Since the lexicon (as usually, but not universally, assumed) is a finite set of words, there are only a finite number of adjectives.  A noun modifier, on the other hand, is a syntactic constituent, which may be built up in a number of ways from other constituents, and there are an infinite number of possible noun modifiers. For instance, a relative clause is a noun modifier, though it is not an adjective.

A good test to distinguish adjectives from other noun modifiers is modifiability by "very", which modifies adjectives, but not other noun modifiers.  For instance, "the bird which was white was eaten with gusto" cannot have a "very" modifying the modifier "which was white", *The bird very which was white ...", but since "white" is an adjective, it is okay to say "The very white bird ..."

And "The bird which was killed was eaten with gusto" can be reduced to "The bird killed was eaten with gusto", where "killed" is the passive participle of "kill", which is not an adjective, so you don't get "*The bird very killed ..." or "*The very killed bird ..."

Another way to tell that adjectives and participles are different syntactic types is to coordinate them with "and", since generally only expressions of the same type can be coordinated:

> the killed and dressed pheasant
>   the red and white pheasant
>   *the red and killed pheasant

Comment: "I took the *very damaged* tire to the garage."  Your test seems to fail for the OP's scenario, as the OP claims the book says "damaged" there is *not* an adjective.

Comment: @Athanasius, the test doesn't fail.  I chose a participle "killed" which happens not to be also an adjective. You've chosen an example with a participle which happens also to be an adjective.

Comment: I didn't "choose an example": I used the exact phrase in OP's post, which OP says *the book in question which the example was drawn from* is not an adjective. If your answer doesn't follow the classification OP requests, how does it answer the question? (And the reason *very* doesn't work with "killed" vs. "damaged" has nothing to do with which is an adjective and which isn't.  It has to do with the fact that "killed" is an absolute state, not subject to degree.  "Dead" is also an adjective and definitely not a verb, but one doesn't say someone is "very dead.")

Comment: @Athanasius, Actually, one *does* say something is "very dead".

Comment: Usually only in an ironic or joking sense.  The point is that your distinction about "very" has to do with [absolute adjectives](https://www.englishgrammar.org/absolute-adjectives/), not with anything about verbs vs. adjectives.  While you can argue that many of the absolute adjectives are used informally with degrees, there are some that basically never used that way, such as "very principal" or "very main" or "very entire."  "Killed" generally is not used with "very" for a similar reason. In contrast, "very" can be used with most participles that don't express an absolute condition.

Comment: @Athanasius, I just don't think you're right about ""very killed"".  By your reasoning, since "injured" is not complete, *"very injured"  should be okay, but it's not.  Or ^"the door was very opened".  And consider also the predicted ambiguity of -ed forms which exist both as participles and as adjectives.  When "very" is added to "Joyce was irritated", the ambiguity is lost, as one would predict from the incompatibility of "very" with participles.

Comment: I agree with your last statement: adding "very" can at times disambiguate the part of speech. But the first part of your comment does not follow from that. I can definitely hear a context where it would be said that someone was "very injured" in an accident or something. But the issue is not "completeness" but rather "absolute" states: a door is either open or closed -- and the "open" case is problematic for your argument since we already have an adjective to use there (i.e., open), so "opened" is obviously a verbal form. I'm not sure I'm going to convince you though, so I'll leave it at that.

Comment: But regardless of all of this discussion (and I'll stop here), my main point in my first comment to you is that your answer doesn't seem to create the right distinction in the case that the OP brings up. Maybe OP's book is wrong: if you want to argue that, fine. But the answer still doesn't seem to differentiate precisely the case that OP mentioned.

Comment: @Athanasius The book isn't wrong and Greg doesn't say it is. OP is misguided in analysing the potential adjectives there as necessarily being past participles (as opposed to being derived from them). So they are extrapolating things from the book that it does not say.

Comment: @Araucaria - thank you for the comment.  I don't know what OP's book says, but if you do, perhaps you can help by referencing that in an answer here and clarifying where OP went off the track.

Comment: @Athanasius What OP is saying is directly analogous to "My book describes *The runner* in *The runner smiled* as a subject and not a noun phrase". It's further confused by them also saying something similar (but not directly analogous) to "Would it be wrong to describe that verb as a noun here?". Those are the main problems for OP.

Comment: @Athanasius Not directly, because, as you point out, OP's examples are ambiguous and the items concerned could actually both be verbs.

Answer (score 2):

Noun modifiers is an overall category, which includes adjectives. Basically, they're any word that, well, modifies a noun in some way. Seems too obvious to be right, but sometimes things do go that way!

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that 'funny' can be used a noun. ('Red'is a better example: "She's a bloody red"). We carry a a lot of word history in our heads but students may not and could come across the word 'funny' as a noun before meeting it as a adjective. I think one has to describe word usage

The very test is like the comparative test and the phrase 'more dead than alive' is quite common. Some previously-absolute words are in transition, such as the notorious 'unique'.

English speakers are rather incline to construct phrases using semantics rather than syntax. It is hard to allow for this in a formal grammar. I think one has to work as synchronically as possible..

Comment: I think you mean *fun*, not *funny*.

Comment: @Araucaria - Ten minutes ago I was reading the Sunday funnies.

Comment: @HotLicks *Fun* is famous for having transmogfrified into an adjective for some speakers.